# Get the last instance of a pattern

Tags: regex, powershell

I need help in a regular expression that will get the **last instance** of a pattern in a single line.

The lines in question are written in the following pattern (separated by slashes):

```
/this/is/how/it/looks/
```

In the example above, I am expecting to get `looks` as the output.

Note that the lines are not uniform and can contain less or more strings than the example.

```
/it/can/be/shorter/
/it/can/also/be/longer/than/most/lines/
```

For the above lines, I expect to get `shorter` and `lines` respectively.

Comment: You probably don't need a regex, what language are you using?

Comment: Will there always be a `/` at the end?

Comment: Are there any methods `lastIndexOf()` and `substring()` in `String` class?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: Hi all - powershell. There will always be a '/' at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/([^/]*)/$
```

is the regex you need.

**Explanation:**

```
/      # Match a slash
(      # Start capturing group number 1
 [^/]* # Match any number of characters except slashes
)      # End capturing group number 1
/      # Match a slash
$      # Match the position at the end of the string
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/qL8zX7/1).

Comment: thanks Tim. I was not aware of the split solution that Casimir proposed (plus I did not even specifiy using powershell) and this is the exact answer to my question.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Powershell, you can write something like this:

```
$line.TrimEnd("/").Split("/")[-1]
```

If you are sure there is always a trailing slash, you can skip the trim step with:

```
$line.Split("/")[-2]
```

Comment: ahh you learn something new everyday. thanks, this works. I didn't know about the use of [-1] - I take it that it's shorthand for "the last instance" ?

Comment: @Yad: Yes it is, and you can have the previous with -2, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\w+(?=/$)`, this will match the last name in each line

Explanation

`\w+` any set of 'word characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _.

`(?=/$)` positive lookahead for '/' followed by the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Abstracted pattern: ( This works for a space, you can replace the first 'literal character' with anything you'd like )

----/----

`(\ .[^\ ]+)(?=$)`

Cheers